# Using a file in android application

Tags: android, file

I am trying to open a file to use for my `android application`, but I am not sure where to save this file so I can use it?

Also how do I use this file once it is saved in the correct place?

It is a `.txt` file.

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To add a file to your application and then read from it at runtime, put it into your `res/raw` directory and then you can read it like this (where `my_file` is the name of your file):

```
try {
    Resources res = getResources();
    InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.my_file);

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in_s));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) { ... }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the swift response, but the problem is I don't know where to place the file in the directory so I can open it within my code as it says file does not exists. Any tips @Buddy?